# An example from Lang's Algebra about primary ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

On page 421 in Lang's Algebra, the author writes

> Let $R$ be a factorial ring with a prime element $t$. Let $A$ be the subring of polynomials $f(X)∈R[X]$ such that 
>   $$f(X)=a_0 + a_1X + \dotsb $$ 
>   with $a_1$ divisible by $t$. Let $P=(tX,X^2)$. Then $P$ is prime.

My question is: why $P$ is prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The claim is wrong: $P$ is not prime in $A$.

The product of elements $t\in A$ and $X^3\in A$ belongs to $P=(tX,X^2)$, but $t\notin P$ and $X^3\notin P$.

**Remark.** If instead we take $P=(tX,X^2,X^3)$, then $P$ is prime and $P^2$ is not primary.

Comment: How to prove the $P$ you gave is prime?

Comment: @Minus22 If one defines a map $A\to R$ by $f\mapsto f(0)$ then we get $A/P\simeq R$.

Comment: I don't see how the map $f \mapsto f(0)$ has kernel $P$, could you explain that, please?

Comment: The kernel is the set of polynomials $f\in A$ such that $f(0)=0$. Then $f=tb_1X+b_2X^2+b_3X^3+\cdots$. Now write $$f=b_1(tX)+(b_2+b_4X^2+\cdots)X^2+(b_3+b_5X^2+\cdots)X^3$$ and this clearly belongs to $P$.